# Adding buttons by a function

Tags: c#, winforms, button, static

I want to add a button, using a function that takes all the arguments in one line, to keep it clean. But if I try to add the button via `This.Controls.Add`, I get an error because the function is static. What should I write instead of `This` (something like `Form1.Controls.Add`) so I can do everything in one function?

Comment: If you need to access the form, why is the method static in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the form as an argument to the static function:

```
public static void CreateButton(Form targetForm, param1, param2, ...) {
    Button b = new Button();
    ...
    targetForm.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

...but unless this method is going to be used to add buttons to a variety of forms, I don't see the advantage of making it static like this.  It seems like a sort of OO anti-pattern.  I would probably make it non-static and use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just have your function *return* the button:

```
//Usage
this.Controls.Add(CreateButton(...));

//Function def 
public static Button CreateButton(...)
{
   Button createdButton = new Button();
   ...
   return createdButton;
}
```

Assignment returns the result of the assignment (so you can chain them). So to inline the assignment:

```
//With a variable (I did *not* say it was good practice to do this)
this.Controls.Add(myVar = CreateButton(...));
```

Comment: But then how would I get to the new button? I need variable that would point to it. I know I can get it, and then add it. But I want to do it in just one line